# Webport Issus with webmessage and multippart messages

Tags: web-services, biztalk, orchestration, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm having an issue while creating orchestration by consuming webservice

Web message response variable name - **msgReponse.webserviceResponse**
multipart message response variable name - **msgResponse.multipartresponse**

I'm receiving the webmessage type(**msgwebserviceResponse.Respone**) from the webport.
Then after receive shape, I'm trying to map that response with another message.
So, here when I try map them by using the transfer shape, When I want to select **msgResponse.multipartresponse** as input schema for the map, I'm seeing **msgResponse.multipartresponse**(I can't see this, as I'm recieving **msgReponse.webserviceResponse** at receive shape)

could you please help me on this?

Thank You,

Comment: your question is very unclear. could you please explain it further and probably add some code?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with yours. Asked a question and got an answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995454/using-biztalk-web-service-to-re-publish-an-internal-web-service).